# Shortest code for assigning values to a List

Tags: java

What could be the shortest possible code for this:

```
public void update(final Product object, final Callback<Product> callback) {
    if(object.getIsDayDependent()) {
        Double priceDay0 = object.getSundayPrice();
        Double priceDay1 = object.getMondayPrice();
        Double priceDay2 = object.getTuesdayPrice();
        Double priceDay3 = object.getWednesdayPrice();
        Double priceDay4 = object.getThursdayPrice();
        Double priceDay5 = object.getFridayPrice();
        Double priceDay6 = object.getSaturdayPrice();
        List<DayPrice> dayPrices = new LinkedList<>();
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(0, priceDay0));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(1, priceDay1));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(2, priceDay2));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(3, priceDay3));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(4, priceDay4));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(5, priceDay5));
        dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(6, priceDay6));
        object.setDayDependent(dayPrices);
    } else {
        object.setPrice(null);
        object.setDayDependent(new LinkedList<>());
    }
    callback.onSuccess(object);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you cannot modify the `Product` class, is that correct?

Comment: Well you could avoid all those local variables using `dayPrices.add(new DayPrice(0, object.getSundayPrice()))` for example. But if you could add `Product.getPrice(int day)` or similar, that would help a lot too...

Comment: this belongs to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How about `List<DayPrice> dayPrices = Arrays.asList(new DayPrice(0, object.getSundayPrice()), new DayPrice(1, object.getMondayPrice()),...)`? But why are you not using the callback argument in your method? What's its purpose?

Comment: @KevinO I can modify Product class somehow, what is your suggestion, maybe that's something that can be worked out in the Product class.

Comment: @JonSkeet nice catch, it actually makes the code shorter with that :-)

Comment: @xybrek, I would then follow the suggestion of @Jon Skeet, and make a single method `double getPrice(...)`. I would, however, not take an `int`, but rather an `enum` (such as java.time.DayOfWeek).

Comment: Why not have Product embody all the work and generate the list, so `dayPrices = object.getDayPrices();`

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't minimize code as much as it reduces the number statements, but it also eliminates unnecessary variables:

```
if(object.getIsDayDependent()) {
    List<Double> prices = Arrays.asList(object.getSundayPrice(),
            object.getMondayPrice(),
            object.getTuesdayPrice(),
            object.getWednesdayPrice(),
            object.getThursdayPrice(),
            object.getFridayPrice(),
            object.getSaturdayPrice());

    object.setDayDependent(IntStream.range(0, 7)
            .mapToObj(i -> new DayPrice(i, prices.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList<Double>::new)));
} else {
    object.setPrice(null);
    object.setDayDependent(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the associated class (Product class) as a challenge, the shortest code I have for this is this:

```
        if(object.getIsDayDependent())) {
            Double priceDay0 = object.getSundayPrice();
            Double priceDay1 = object.getMondayPrice();
            Double priceDay2 = object.getTuesdayPrice();
            Double priceDay3 = object.getWednesdayPrice();
            Double priceDay4 = object.getThursdayPrice();
            Double priceDay5 = object.getFridayPrice();
            Double priceDay6 = object.getSaturdayPrice();
            object.setDayDependent(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
                    new DayPrice(0, priceDay0),
                    new DayPrice(1, priceDay1),
                    new DayPrice(2, priceDay2),
                    new DayPrice(3, priceDay3),
                    new DayPrice(4, priceDay4),
                    new DayPrice(5, priceDay5),
                    new DayPrice(6, priceDay6))));
        }
```

Not much, but maybe there's some more clever way that someone can answer.

Comment: The reason I wrapped it with `LinkedList` is due to reflection used in my app, so just disregard with I didn't use just a `List`